# Concrete lid in basement-what is it for?

Tags: water, basement, pump, sump

Does anyone know what this heavy concrete lid is for? It is approximately 2ftx1.5ft. It is 6-7 ft away from my sump pump. I started getting little water leak under the lid and sump pump works fine regularly nowadays. House built around 1959 in MA.  Thanks[image]

Comment: It looks more like an equipment pad.

Comment: If it is, in fact, a lid, why not lift it up and see what is under it?

Comment: Why wasting time guessing, just lift it up

Comment: Seeing more of the surroundings might or might not help. Without that all we can do is guess. With that we still might not be able to do more than guess.

Comment: downvote ... the question cannot possibly be answered without lifting the lid

Comment: Thanks all for responding. It is not a pad , it is sealed and  heavy- two persons could not move. it is an open concept unfinished area in basement- nothing around it. I just wanted to see if this thing is common in houses built around same time - and someone else might have something similar in their houses. We moved very recently. Thanks

Comment: You may want to ask neighbors, living in houses built around the same time, if they have anything similar in their basements, and if so, if they know what it's for. If you thump it with a rubber mallet, does it give off a different sound than if you thump the floor next to it? That would tell you if it's hollow underneath or if it's a footing of some sort (solid underneath).

Comment: 2ft x 1ft?  It [should weigh](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28+density+of+concrete%29+*+%282ft+x+1ft+x+2+inches%29+in+lb) about 25 pounds. If two people can't move (not lift, move) it, it must be permanently sealed shut.   If I bought this house and I had water seeping out of it, I would force it open or smash it up to discover what's underneath.

Answer (score 3):

If the sump pump is working nearby, but water is newly coming out, it's probably covering some sort of sewer/drain access and you probably have a developing problem on that front (1959 - could be [Orangeburg "pipe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangeburg_pipe) where the cast iron ends, typically 10 feet outside the building, that's given up the ghost.)

You could try flushing some non-toxic septic dye, and see if color shows up in the seepage.

Comment: *Hmm - of course, if you happen to be located in **Innsmouth**, it's probably cemented down to try to contain some eldritch horror beneath the basement.*

Comment: Thanks, I will check this orangeburg pipe thing. and ask neighbors.  We have a septic system and  original cast iron pipe is on the other side of the house where bathrooms located above. Still everything connected to this original cast iron pipe. This lid is on other side-front of house -

Comment: You should edit that information into your question.  Remember, we can't see the relative locations of things in your basement, so we need you to supply that information. A flat masonry chisel parallel to the floor should crack it loose if it's "cemented down to the floor" but not set down into it, as which point it should be possible to slide it sideways (using a flat pry-bar for leverage) and investigate.

Comment: `<totally off-topic>` that page on Orangeburg pipe was interesting. In particular "power plants used exhaust _steam_ from their generators to _dry_ lengths of fiber conduit" - how in the world was _steam_ used to _dry_ anything??? (Unless it was used to turn a fan that blew cool dry air on it (like a turbo charger), but the Wiki page doesn't say that.)

Comment: You generally put the steam in a pipe, which makes the pipe hot, which makes dry heat (outside the pipe) and condensate (inside the pipe with the steam.) Can be a fancier heat exchanger, but plain old steel/iron pipe will do. And normally a steam plant wants the condensate back for re-use (treating feed water for a boiler is expensive.)

Comment: @FreeMan The uninstalled bits of pipe were dried before being sealed.  Perhaps using the  [principle of superheated steam drying](https://www.igb.fraunhofer.de/en/research/thermal-separation-processes/drying/principle-of-superheated-steam-drying.html)  This is a different principle, kind of opposite actually, to the condensing one.  I don't know which one was used.

Comment: Ahhh... steam heating a room to dry the pipe, but not exposing the pipe itself to the steam. I was envisioning the steam flowing through the pipes to be dried and was really lost. Wow... 3 cups of coffee already this morning and I still didn't get that until y'all drew me a picture.